# Installed packages periodically removed

Tags: apt, package-management

Every now and them, the packages I install are getting removed from my machine.

The installation command:

`sudo apt -y install <package_name>`

I don't do anything that removes those packages.

Looking through the logs, I found in the apt log:

```
startup packages configure
startup packages remove
status installed <package_name> 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1
remove <package_name> 4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1 <none>
```

What could be the reason for that behavior and How can I disable it?